# .net Excel Interop

Tags: .net, excel

How can I get the used size of a sheet in such a format : `$A$1:$G$25`?
I use:

```
xls.PublishObjects.Add(
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSourceType.xlSourceRange, 
outputFile, 
wsCurrent.Name, 
"$A$1:$G$25", 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHtmlType.xlHtmlStatic, 
"dsg", 
"").Publish(true);
```

But I need to get the whole sheet, not only that `$A$1:$G$25` range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to export the whole sheet as HTML? If so you can use the following code without needing to calculate the used range.

```
xls.PublishObjects.Add(
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSourceType.xlSourceSheet, 
"D:\\Documents\\test2.html",
"Sheet1",
"Sheet1",
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHtmlType.xlHtmlStatic,
"dsg",
"").Publish(true);
```

Otherwise you can use the following code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = xls.Worksheets[1].UsedRange;
string rangeName = range.Address;
```